# Standalone.sty error

Tags: document-classes, standalone

there can anyone point out why this file is not working? I tried windows and ubuntu. The [two related files](https://github.com/Coding511/Sample-File-Latex) and the main latex file are attached.
Thanks

```
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,fleqn]{book}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{import}
%\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1.25cm, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm, bindingoffset=1.25cm, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{array,multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcase}
% Load the package with the acronym option
%\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
%\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossariX}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{tabto}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}

\pagestyle{fancy}           % Sets fancy header and footer
%\ChNameUpperCase
%\ChTitleUpperCase
%\ChRuleWidth{3pt}
%\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Huge\rm}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}    % Width of head rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}    % Width of head rule
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5 pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} %
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}    % Width of head rule
}
\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{192,192,192}
\definecolor{myblack}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\scshape\huge\bfseries\color{myblack}}
{   \filleft%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
    outer sep=0pt,
    text width=2.5cm,
    minimum height=3cm,
    fill=mygrey,
    font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90},
    %font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont,
    align=center
    ] (num) {\thechapter};
    \node[
    rotate=90,
    anchor=south,
    font=\color{black}\large
    %font=\color{black}\Large\normalfont
    ] at ([xshift=-5pt]num.west) {\textls[180]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}};  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{10pt}
{\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt\LARGE}
%{\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt\LARGE\sffamily}


\hypersetup{
    %   colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
} 
 
%\title{Thesis}
%\author{Author-1}
%\date{August 2014}
 

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % Define Your Entries Here
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Generate the glossary
%\makeglossaries
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\begin{document}
 
    % \maketitle
    %\cleardoublepage
    % \section*{Title Page}

    \import{sections/}{FrontPage}
    \BlankPage
    \import{sections/}{TitlePage}
    \BlankPage
    
    
    \section*{\Large \scshape \filcenter Certificate of Approval}
    \import{sections/}{CertificateOfApproval}
    \BlankPage
    
    %\section*{\hfil \huge Certificate\hfil}
    \import{sections/}{SupervisorCertificate}
    \BlankPage
    
    \section*{ \Large \scshape \filcenter\scshape Declaration }
    \import{sections/}{Declaration}
    \BlankPage  
    
    %\section*{\Large \scshape \filcenter Acknowledgements }
    
    \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
    \import{sections/}{Acknowledgements}
    \BlankPage
        
    %\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae}
    %\import{sections/}{CurriculumVita}
    %\BlankPage 
    
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    \import{sections/}{Abstract}
    \BlankPage
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \BlankPage
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
    %\newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \BlankPage
    %   \newpage
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Tables} 
    \listoftables   
    \BlankPage
 
    %----------------------------------
    %CHAPTER 
    %----------------------------------
    \begin{savequote}[0.55\linewidth]
        An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.
        \qauthor{Benjamin Franklin}
    \end{savequote}     
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \import{chapters/}{Chapter01}

    \chapter{Literature Review}
    \import{chapters/}{Chapter02}
    

    \chapter{3}
    \import{chapters/}{Chapter03}
        
    
    \chapter{4}
    \import{chapters/}{Chapter04}
    

    \chapter{5}
    \import{chapters/}{Chapter05}
    
    \chapter{6}
    \import{chapters/}{Chapter06}   
 
    \chapter{7}
    \import{chapters/}{Chapter07}   

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{apa-good}%apalike
    \bibliography{PhDThesis}
 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\scshape\huge\bfseries\color{myblack}}
{   \filleft%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
    outer sep=0pt,
    text width=2.5cm,
    minimum height=3cm,
    fill=mygrey,
    font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90},
    %font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont,
    align=center
    ] (num) {\thechapter};
    \node[
    %rotate=90,
    %anchor=south,
    font=\color{black}\large
    %font=\color{black}\Large\normalfont
    ] at ([yshift=18pt]num) {\textls[180]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}};  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{10pt}
{\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt\LARGE}
    
    
    \chapter*{Curriculum Vitae}
    \import{sections/}{CurriculumVita}
    \BlankPage
 
\end{document}
```

The errors are many; the first few lines I copied here.

[image]

Comment: shorten your example. Remove all packages not related to the error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks, so Should I remove all packages not related to standalone? I am not sure about this, this is a sample thesis with 5 chapters. I have not attached the full file. So is it executable in this stage?

Comment: the purpose of posting code is to let other people debug the error if it has `\import{chapters/}{Chapter04}` we can not run it, if it has (say)  `\usepackage{tikz}` and that is not required to show the error, it slows everything down and makes tracing harder.

Comment: It is hard and made me post the question here, sir. I have removed all chapters from the document class and still getting the same error.

Comment: Can anyone suggest what to do in this case? I can not upload the whole thesis :(

Comment: Uploading the whole thesis will not work because no one else will be able to run the code. To find out where the typing error is, comment out all the `\import`s and `\BlankPage`s, then run: if it compiles without error, good, that is the starting position. Then, going line by line, uncomment and run, until the error returns. Then, to find out which packages,  comment out each package and run - if the error disappears, that package is needed to reproduce the error - uncomment it and continue to comment/run the remaining packages until only minimal code remains for the error. Then we can look.

Comment: Correction: no-one can look in the `\import`s. Unrelated question: why are you not using `\input` in the main document, which `standalone` package needs to input a picture, etc? The instruction manual for the thesis should have information about how to use it.

Comment: "I have removed all chapters from the document" so remove them from the example above. no one can help you if you just show a "summary" of errors from an editor screenshot, not the real tex errors from the log and post 250 lines of code almost all of which are unrelated to the error, and which no one can run as it references files we do not have.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sir can I share my overleaf file with you please? Regards

Comment: no, make a small self contained example and add iit here. you can always do that. start by copying your project so you do not damage your real document then delete all the text not required to show the problem then delete every package not required for the small text